# I am new to smart contracts and I am withdrawing amounts in several lots.My question is do I have to complete before bank transfer

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

After each transfer.It goes to a wallet address but where I want it go.Does smart contracts hold onto it ,until all withdrawals are complete.

Answer (score 0):

After each withdrawal, the funds are sent to a wallet address.

The smart contract will hold onto the funds until all withdrawals are complete.

Once all withdrawals are complete, the funds will be transferred to the bank account that is associated with the smart contract.

Let me know if you need any help more.

Thanks.

Comment: Your response is very helpful Ari.

Comment: Good to hear that.

Thanks @AndrewSinkinson

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts, in general, do not "hold onto" funds in the same way that a traditional account or wallet might. Instead, the transfer of funds within a smart contract is determined by the logic written in the contract code. But, the contract could accumulate funds over time and then release them under certain conditions or trigger events.

The specific situation needs to be determined based on the logic and rules of the smart contract.